# Exception when parsing with JSon

Tags: codenameone

Since today my app throws an Exception when parsing an InputStream with the JSon-class. The exception is not thrown in the simulator - only with my iOS-Build on the device. The Exception added below.

Because I did not made any changes in this part of my app - and because of the fact, that it does not happen in the simulator - I would like to ask, if it could be a bug in the codenameone-lib?

```
[Network Thread] 0:0:53,832 - Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
   at java_util_Arrays.checkOffsetAndCount:41
   at java_io_ByteArrayOutputStream.write:195
   at java_io_InputStreamReader.copy:61
   at java_io_InputStreamReader.readInputStream:52
   at java_io_InputStreamReader.complete:46
   at java_io_InputStreamReader.read:120
   at com_codename1_io_JSONParser_ReaderClass.read:124
   at com_codename1_io_JSONParser.parse:188
   at com_codename1_io_JSONParser.parse:492
   at de_zeitkuenstler_gtd_data_DBXAccess_3.readResponse:758
   at com_codename1_io_ConnectionRequest.performOperation:797
   at com_codename1_io_NetworkManager_NetworkThread.run:282
   at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
   at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
[Network Thread] 0:0:53,839 - Exception during JSON parsing at row: 1 column: 1 buffer: 
[Network Thread] 0:0:4,854 - Codename One revisions: bf8a99519da709667dd7d6e5b9ee4c4e5c231618
```

EDIT:
The error does not occur with the Android build on a real device. And it does not occur in the simulator. I think the error has to do with the size of the response-body. It happens, when parsing the response from DropBox http-API with the function "listFiles" with more than 38 files are in the DropBox-directory. On Android more than 170 files in the DropBox-directory does not lead to the exception.

EDIT 2:
I found a way to solve the problem - but I'm not happy with it.
The task is to read the response from a HTTP-Request.

This code works now without exception:

```
ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest()
        {
            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException
            {
                try
                {
                    if( input instanceof BufferedInputStream)
                        ((BufferedInputStream)input).setDisableBuffering(true);

                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    int c = input.read();
                    int i = 0;
                    while (c >= 0)
                    {
                        sb.append((char) c);

                        c = input.read();
                        i++;
                    }
                    StaticLogger.log("char count: " + i);

                    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(sb.toString());
                    ...
```

When buffering is not disabled, then this exception is thrown on my iOS-Device (but not in Simulator oder on an Android device):

```
[Network Thread] 0:0:1,827 - Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - 8192
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com_codename1_io_BufferedInputStream.read:312
    at de_zeitkuenstler_gtd_data_DBXAccess_3.readResponse:758
    at com_codename1_io_ConnectionRequest.performOperation:797
    at com_codename1_io_NetworkManager_NetworkThread.run:282
    at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
    at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
```

This looks very strange for me. Do you have any idea what the reason could be?

Comment: It would really help to know the string in question.  Q: Any chance you could capture it (e.g. read from Stringstream, copy into a temp string, and call JSONParser with the sttring)?

Comment: Assuming this happens on the simulator you can open the Network Monitor tool and see the outgoing/incoming requests in the network pipe

Comment: I think something is wrong with the iOS-build. The error does not occur with the Android build on a real device. And it does not occur in the simulator. I think the error has to do with the size of the response-body. It happens, when parsing the response from DropBox http-API with the function "listFiles" with more than 38 files are in the DropBox-directory. On Android more than 170 files in the DropBox-directory does not lead to the exception. Do you have any tipp what I can do?

Comment: I found a (strange) solution for the problem (see description above) - but it looks as if there is something totally wrong. Do you have any idea what the reason could be?